# How to ensure new instances of a Blazor components are created

Tags: blazor

I'm seeing some odd behaviour with Blazor with event hooks and the `firstRender` argument of `OnAfterRender`.

My parent component creates a dynamic set of child components:

Parent:

```
@if (_childObjects != null)
{
    @foreach (var childObject in _childObjects )
    {
        <ChildComponent ChildObject=@childObject />
     }
 }
```

Child:

```
[Parameter]
public ChildObject ChildObject { get; set;  }
```

What happens is on clicking certain buttons that parent re-renders with a new set of child objects.  I expect it to create new instances of `ChildComponent` for that, which it partially does.

But somehow when it hits this code:

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
```

... at this point, the value of `firstRender` is false and everything seems to be already initialised as per the previous render of the parent.

Comment: Why do you 'initialize' in OnAfterRender?

Comment: I unwire/rewire some event hooks on first render, rather than in `OnInitialized` but most of the "initialize" is in the right place.   There was a good reason at the time!

Comment: [Polite] There are rarely good reasons to do anything but JSInterop in `OnAfterRender`.  The normal reason is you haven't got your component logic right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect it to create new instances of `ChildComponent`

Why?  Blazor sees a (Child) Component with a different parameter.

You can help the differ by adding @key, I think that will do what you want:

```
@foreach (var childObject in _childObjects )
{
    <ChildComponent @key="childObject" ChildObject="childObject" />
 }
```

Comment: yes that has fixed it.  however - in answer to why - it seems more logical to create new instances when writing markup for multiple instances, imo.

Comment: No, in lots of instances that would be inefficient. And you can control it this way.